# Ansible check if mysql user exist

Tags: mysql, ansible

not sure if it is even technically possible in ansible, but can I check if user exists and set it as variable in ansible? I was not able to find it in https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/mysql/mysql_user_module.html but still curious if there is "workaround".

Comment: Use the above module in [check mode](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_checkmode.html#enforcing-or-preventing-check-mode-on-tasks)

Comment: Hey,
In the module, if you test the user it will be not changed if already exists or changed if created.
You can "register" the output module of the module and use it in the next tasks